# Cakephp tmp is not write able

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3

When I download sample project from github 
I paste in to My new project in folder app
I got problem

```
Warning (512): C:\xampp\htdocs\Tags\app\tmp\cache\ is not writable       
[CORE\cake\libs\cache\file.php, line 267]

Warning (512): \persistent\ is not writable [CORE\cake\libs\cache\file.php, line 267]

Warning (512): \models\ is not writable [CORE\cake\libs\cache\file.php, line 267]
```

before I paste sample project
no problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [this post](https://web.archive.org/web/20110629085121/http://cakephp.19694.n2.nabble.com/Tmp-is-not-writable-td5826869.html).  Try the recursive chown of the tmp directory.